How do I recreate this type of chart from screenshot in Excel?
I have chart like below. I am trying to recreate something like this in Excel. My call is to use XY chart, but I cant make it represent each row as different axis. Is this even possible in Excel?
Or do I have it make each axis as separate chart (should work for me as well).



Here is excel chart to show what data represents:

Left side of the axis: Min value of a period.
Right side of the axis: Max value of a period.
Black dot: Last value (from last day/week/month).
Yellow rectangle: Current value.

Excel table for first three rows:



row
Current
last
max
min




row1
4
7
17
4


row2
-15
-18
-15
-50


row3
-7
-7
0
-30




You need to normalize your data. Assuming your original table is in A1:E4
Use the following formula to populate a second table:
=(B2-$E2)/ABS($E2-$D2)

Sample result:

Then use this table to generate a chart and assign the values of the first table as labels for the various data points

Just to precise last part: you mean select one row, make XY chart and then use lables from the first chart?

You should be able to make a chart from the entire table and yes, use the first chart for the labels
